# Html Inserting multiple row in the database at once php/mysql

Tags: php

I have a form with 5 textfields. I want users to fill out the form for any number of people then click next to enter an amount. Then I want to calculate the amount for the number of users filled then submit to the database. For example, when a user fills out the form for 5 people and then proceeds to fill the amount which calculates the total and splits it back to the different rows.

1.. user fills a form for more than one person.   2.. the information are been held in an array.  3.. the user proceed to the payment page , if he fills for 5 people e.g if payment for one person is $500 , the code calculate for 5 which is 500*5 = $2500 but still insert $500 each of the rows.

Comment: Can you show a sample code snippet? It is hard to imagine what you are trying to tell us.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Ryan, It's quite a lot to visualise, do you have any current code you could possibly show us to give us a better understanding of what you are asking?

Comment: 1.. user fills a form for more than one person.   2.. the information are been held in an array.  3.. the user proceed to the payment page , if he fills for 5 people e.g if payment for one person is $500 , the code calculate for 5 which is 500*5 = $2500 but still insert $500 each of the rows.

Comment: We need to see what your data schema is and what the pages are called? There's not much help we can provide unless you can show us what you have so far

Comment: Please show us your code.  It is very difficult to give any corrections to you without seeing what you're doing.